# Is the verb 'taking' a gerund in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

*"I remember my father **taking** me to the zoo."*

Is 'taking' a gerund? And why?

Comment: Yes, it's a gerund in that sentence, I would say (though others use the term differently, or not at all). The reason it's a gerund is that it is the main verb in the gerund clause _my father taking me to the zoo_, which is the direct object of the verb _remember_ and is therefore a noun complement clause. _Gerund_ is the name I use for an _-ing_ verb form that appears as the main verb in a noun complement clause. The reason all this is possible is because the main verb is _remember_; try using _know, think, want,_ or _seem_ instead of _remember_ and see what happens.

Comment: @John Lawler: _The reason all this is possible is because the main verb is remember; try using know, think, want, or seem instead of remember and see what happens._ Sorry if this sounds stupid but what's wrong with _I **want** my father taking/to take me to the zoo?_ What's with your last sentence in the previous comment? :)

Comment: _I want my father to take me to the zoo_ is more common, but _I want my father taking me to the zoo_ is grammatical, if rarer. It sounds like a contrastive emphatic that's repeating the structure of a previous remark.

Answer (score -1):

*Pace* John, the answer is no. Here's why,

[**Gerund**](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/index.html):

> A verbal that ends in *-ing* and *functions as a noun*. The term
> *verbal* indicates that a gerund is based on a verb and therefore expresses action or a state of being.
> However, since a gerund functions as a noun, it occupies some
> positions in a sentence that a noun ordinarily would, for example:
> subject, direct object, subject complement, and object of a
> preposition.

In the sentence, "*I remember my father taking me to the zoo.*" the verb **taking** isn't functioning as a noun; it's functioning as a present tense verb in the progressive aspect within a noun clause whose subject is "my father". The noun clause "my father taking me to the zoo" is the direct object of the main verb 'remember'.